# php Array values dont get inported to DB

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a browser game in order to learn html,css,php and MySQL. And i wrote the code below to allow players to build new buildings. The table loads with all buildings, and everything work fine, even the insert to the DB. But as i'm new to this i have a problem where all the values that should be put into the DB are empty. the $_SESSION[user_id] works. But not the values from the array.
So i think the problem might be that i dont know how to get the values correctly..

So if someone would like to help me here it would be much appreciated and educational for me! :)

```
function buildings() {
    global $database;
    global $player;
    global $self_link;


    // Fetch buildings
    $result = $database->query("SELECT * FROM buildings");
    $buildings = array();
    while($building = $database->fetch($result)) {
        $buildings[$building['id']] = $building;
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['build'])) {
        $building_id = (int)$_POST['building_id'];
        $amount = $_POST['amount'];

        try {
            if($player->money < $buildings[$building_id]['cost']) {
                throw new Exception("You do not have enough money to build this!");
            }

            // Purchase technique
            $player->money -= $buildings[$building_id]['cost'] * $amount;
            $database->query("INSERT INTO player_buildings (owner_id, name, power_use, life, att_inf, att_veh, att_air, att_sea) 
                                    VALUES ('$_SESSION[user_id]', '$buildings[name]', '$power_use', '$life', '$att_inf', '$att_veh', '$att_air', '$att_sea')");
            $player->update();

            echo "Debugg: Buildings have been added.... I hope..";
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

    }
    // Display form 
    echo "<table style='width:900px;'>
        <tr>
            <th style='width:40% text-align:left;'>Name</th>
            <th style='width:50%;'>Description</th>
            <th style='width:5%;'>Price</th>
            <th style='width:5%;'>Power Usage</th>
            <th style='width:5%;'>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>";
        foreach($buildings as $id => $building) {   
            echo "<tr>
                <td>{$building['name']}</td>
                <td>{$building['description']}</td>
                <td>{$building['cost']}</td>
                <td>{$building['power_use']}</td>
                <td>    
                    <form action='$self_link' method='POST'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='building_id' value='$id' />
                        <input style='width:40px' type='number' name='amount' value='amount' />
                        <input type='submit' name='build' value='Build' />
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>";
        }

    echo "</table>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $buildings[$building['id']] = $building;
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    VALUES ('$_SESSION[user_id]', '$buildings[name]', '$power_[..snip..]
                                              ^^^^
```

Unless `$building['id']` resolves into the literal word `name`, you're accessing undefined fields in your array...

Turn on `error_reporting` and `display_errors` to confirm - if that is an incorrect key, you'll get `undefined index` warnings.

Plus you're likely vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). And unless you've enabled exceptions in your DB library, you're simply ASSUMING the query will never fail.

Comment: I have tried the error reporting and display, all i get is Error:30711, wich i tried to google and it should not be something to worry about from what i read there?

Comment: 30711 is just the integer representation of the `E_ALL` error bitmask. but you still should have error_reporting turned on. it should never be off in the first place on a devel/debug system.

Comment: Yeah, well, they are both just outputing "30711" tho.. Thanks anyway mate! I appreciate it. :)

Comment: `error_reporting()` changes the error bitmask, and returns the current one. it's not something you can just call...

Comment: Okey, my bad! :) I will seek more knowlege i guess!